# check the product is present in session array and if present increase the count value for that product using php

Tags: php, arrays, session

i am adding products to session as array but before adding that product to session how to check that product is present in session array or not.
If the product is present i want to increase the count of that product, if not add that product to session array. My php code is given below.

```
session_start(); 
if(empty( $_SESSION['fields1'] )) {
  $_SESSION['fields1'] = array();
}    
$qty = 1;

$id = $_POST['id'];
$name = $_POST['name']; 
$description = $_POST['description'];
$cnt = 0;
print_r($_SESSION['fields1']);
if (! empty($_SESSION['fields1'])){
    foreach ($_SESSION['fields1'] as $key=>$val){
            if ($id == $val['id']){
                 $qty = $val['qty']++;
                 //echo "qty ===".$qty;
                 $_SESSION['fields1'][$cnt]['qty'] =  $val['qty']++;                     
            }
            else
            {
                $arrayval =  array('id' => $id,'name' => $name,'description' => $description,'qty' => $qty);
                array_push($_SESSION['fields1'] ,$arrayval );
            }
            $cnt++;
    }

}else{
    $arrayval =  array('id' => $id,'name' => $name,'description' => $description,'qty' => $qty);
    array_push($_SESSION['fields1'] ,$arrayval );
}
//print_r($_SESSION['fields1']);
echo json_encode($_SESSION['fields1']);
```

Comment: in php you can use in_array('1', $_SESSION['sessionname']);

Comment: 3 votes ? Amazing ^_^

Answer (score 0):

If `$id` is ID of product and `fields` is array of products, try something like this:

```
if(empty($_SESSION['fields'][$id]))
    $_SESSION['fields'][$id]['qty'] = 1;
else
    $_SESSION['fields'][$id]['qty']++;
```